# Balancing vertical spacing between images or boxes in a page

Tags: spacing, graphics, vertical-alignment

I've have a series group made of text and of images (1 to 6 images per group). I would like the vertical spacing between images to be well balanced in a page.

Here is a minimal working example (for illustrative purposes here, real images are replaced with a black box and page frames are displayed):

https://fr.sharelatex.com/project/5860184917ccee00403ef8ca

```
\documentclass[DIV=12,paper=a4,10pt,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[
    showframe,
    paperwidth=210mm,
    paperheight=297mm,
    top=27.5mm,
    bottom=27.5mm,
    inner=20mm,
    outer=20mm,
    marginparsep=7mm,
    marginparwidth=48mm,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\blindtext[5]
\vfill
\makebox[\textwidth]{
\centering
    \rule{8cm}{5cm}
}
\vfill

\clearpage
\section{Section}
\blindtext[5]
\vfill
\makebox[\textwidth]{
\centering
    \rule{8cm}{5cm}
}
\vfill

\vfill
\makebox[\textwidth]{
\centering
    \rule{8cm}{5cm}
}
\vfill

\vfill
\makebox[\textwidth]{
\centering
    \rule{8cm}{5cm}
}
\vfill

\clearpage
\section{Section}
\blindtext[5]
\vfill
\makebox[\textwidth]{
\centering
    \rule{8cm}{5cm}
}
\vfill

\vfill
\makebox[\textwidth]{
\centering
    \rule{8cm}{5cm}
}
\vfill

\vfill
\makebox[\textwidth]{
\centering
    \rule{8cm}{2cm}
}
\vfill

\vfill
\makebox[\textwidth]{
\centering
    \rule{8cm}{5cm}
}
\vfill
\end{document}
```

Typical cases:

- 1st case: looks good ! Picture seems to have equal amount of free space above it (up to bottom of the text) and below (down to bottom of the page)

[image: Looks good ! Picture seems to have equal amount of free space above it (up to bottom of the text) and below (down to bottom of the page)]

- 2nd case: 1st picture is missing some vertical spacing below, 2nd image is missing space at the top, 3rd image looks good

[image: 1st picture is missing some vertical spacing below, 2nd image is missing space at the top, 3rd image looks good]

- 3rd case: same as previous case and 3rd and 4th images look good

[image: same as previous case, 3rd and 4th images look good]

The real document is about 450 pages with 200 different sections (groups) where the length of the text varies as well as the number of images.

Answer (score 3):

apart from the vertical space, each image gave

```
Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 70--74
```

due to the paragraph indentation.

also `\centering` does nothing inside `\makebox` (as it is horizontal mode).

However normally space is discarded at a page break, but here it appears that you want to keep it so you can use `\vspace*`

[image]

```
\documentclass[DIV=12,paper=a4,10pt,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[
    showframe,
    paperwidth=210mm,
    paperheight=297mm,
    top=27.5mm,
    bottom=27.5mm,
    inner=20mm,
    outer=20mm,
    marginparsep=7mm,
    marginparwidth=48mm,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\blindtext[5]

\nopagebreak
\vspace*{\fill}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{
    \rule{8cm}{5cm}
}

\nopagebreak
\vspace*{\fill}

\clearpage
\section{Section}
\blindtext[5]

\nopagebreak
\vspace*{\fill}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{
    \rule{8cm}{5cm}
}

\nopagebreak
\vspace*{\fill}

\pagebreak[0]

\vspace*{\fill}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{
    \rule{8cm}{5cm}
}

\nopagebreak
\vspace*{\fill}

\pagebreak[0]

\vspace*{\fill}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{
    \rule{8cm}{5cm}
}

\vspace*{\fill}

\clearpage
\section{Section}
\blindtext[5]

\nopagebreak
\vspace*{\fill}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{
    \rule{8cm}{5cm}
}

\nopagebreak
\vspace*{\fill}

\pagebreak[0]

\vspace*{\fill}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{
    \rule{8cm}{5cm}
}

\nopagebreak
\vspace*{\fill}

\pagebreak[0]

\vspace*{\fill}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{
    \rule{8cm}{2cm}
}

\nopagebreak
\vspace*{\fill}

\pagebreak[0]

\vspace*{\fill}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{
    \rule{8cm}{5cm}
}

\nopagebreak
\vspace*{\fill}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks David ! It works. However in some cases (e.g., long introducing paragraph + single image alone on a page) spacing at page breaks still doesn't work. I'm not able to reproduce them in a minimal working example, so I will try to first solve this before coming back.